How can i solve this molecular+ error?
This error appears every time that i tried to active the addon, i alredy try to download and install blender and the addon again and don't have success.

This looks like a bug with the addon, I would recommend checking the github of the addon.

I solved my problem, thanks. On GitHub, the developer mentioned that Blender 4.1 is not supported yet for the addon, but he provided a link where you can download the latest version for Blender 4.1.
